# Types of Research for comparing two Groups

Tags: statistics, test, well-being, survey, reproducible-research

i am planning to do an empirical research for my Thesis, which is about the influence of exercise on the psychological and subjective well-being of individuals (60-90 years of age).

hypothesis: Seniors, that exercise regularly have a higher subjective well being.

I don't have a statistical background so I'd be happy, if there is anyone who could help me.

I was thinking about doing a survey with two groups. On the one hand, I pick a group of 50 individuals, who are exercising for more than 2 years on a regular basis. On the other hand I'll pick a group of 50 individuals that don't exercise at all.

I want to statistically compare these Groups based on a standardized Questionnaire on Well-being.

My Question is: Is this a good approach to test such a hypothesis? I'd be glad to hear, what types of empirical studies exists and what would be the most optimal and scientific approach, to test my hypothesis.

As for now, I think my approach would be a two sample t test, where I obtain my data through the standardized questionnaire on two distinct groups.

Comment: How are you going to get your two groups?

Comment: Asking if a particular approach to research is *good* is soliciting for opinions really which is not on topic on any StackExchange site. If you were to look for the pros and cons of such an approach, that's fine because you are then left with the ability to assess its merits **yourself** based on what you wish to find and any time constraints you may have.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question is too broad for this forum, I recommend instead to start with a literature review, and ask specific questions about anything not clear, as I expect that much research has already been conducted regarding your hypothesis, and you can probably use a previous study as a template for yours.  If you are looking for basic associative evidence, then a simple t-test of a standardized scale would do fine.  However, such a survey would not establish cause and effect, and not account for memory biases, validity, or sampling / recruitment issues - too much to cover.

Comment: You are at the right place, but as @ArnonWeinberg pointed out, start with an initial broad literature review. It will help you formulate a better question here, at which point you can edit this question in line with the feedback you got and we will gladly reopen it! +1 good luck with your research.